# Using ElementRef in a Pipe

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement [malarkey](https://github.com/yuanqing/malarkey) as an Angular2 pipe. The idea is that you'll be able to write an expression like `['foo','bar','baz'] | malarkey` and get the typing effect. Malarkey needs to select the parent element, so I want to set up my pipe to grab the ElementRef and pass the selector through to malarkey:

```ts
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var malarkey: any;

@Pipe({
  name: 'malarkey'
})
export class MalarkeyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  ...
  elem: HTMLElement;

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.elem = el.nativeElement;
  }

  transform(value: [string], args?: {}): any {
    if (!value) return value;
    var elem = this.elem;
    let opts = {
      ...
    };


    let act = malarkey(elem,opts);
    return value.forEach(function(w) {
      act.type(w).pause().delete();
    });
  }

}
```

I get an exception: No provider for ElementRef!

What's happening here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The elementRef isn't available for injection at the level of the pipe. Only for components and corresponds to the root element of the component.

That being said, you could provide an elementRef as input of your pipe. Here is a sample:

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'malarkey'
})
export class MalarkeyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  ...

  transform(value: [string], elem:ElementRef): any {
    if (!value) return value;
    var elem = this.elem.nativeElement;
    let opts = {
      ...
    };

    let act = malarkey(elem,opts);
    return value.forEach((w) => {
      act.type(w).pause().delete();
    });
  }
}
```

You can use it this way:

```
['foo','bar','baz'] | malarkey:elementRef
```

To get the elementRef within the component, you can inject it in the constructor (root element) or leverage the `ViewChild` decorator:

```js
@Component({
  template: `
    <div>
      <div #test>Some div</div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class SomeComponent {
  @ViewChild('test')
  elementRef:ElementRef;
}
```

Comment: what does "you can inject it in the constructor"mean? Im trying to do this, but the pipe is used in a forLoop, so the viewchild wouldnt work for me.